# Javascript: Get data from <span> inside <td>

Tags: javascript, html, variables, html-table

I have a html [price-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EvNM.jpg) which is not generated by me and I cannot edit it. How can I put each table data (under 'Price' column) into 3 separate Javascript variables and trim off the '$' so that the variables are of number datatype? I would like to use the variables for later calculation.

Below is the HTML codes for the table:

```
<table class="pricing-rules">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th>Qty </th>
         <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>10-499</td>
         <td>
            <span class="price-amount">
               <span class="currencySymbol">$</span>
               0.29
               </span>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>500-999</td>
         <td>
            <span class="price-amount">
               <span class="currencySymbol">$</span>
               0.28
            </span>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>1000+</td>
         <td>
            <span class="price-amount">
               <span class="currencySymbol">$</span>
               0.26
            </span>
         </td>
      </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add some code to your question! As it stands, you're asking about JavaScript but haven't included any of your own :)

Comment: You'll also need to show expected results, as your question is a bit vague.

Comment: _"3 separate Javascript variables"_ with what data exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("price-amount");
var price = [];
for(i=0;i<spans.length;i++)
{
 price.push(parseFloat(spans[i].innerHTML.replace( /^\D+/g, '')));
 
}
 console.log(price);
```

```html
<table class="pricing-rules">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th>Qty </th>
         <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>10-499</td>
         <td>
            <span class="price-amount">
               <span class="currencySymbol">$</span>
               0.29
               </span>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>500-999</td>
         <td>
            <span class="price-amount">
               <span class="currencySymbol">$</span>
               0.28
            </span>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>1000+</td>
         <td>
            <span class="price-amount">
               <span class="currencySymbol">$</span>
               0.26
            </span>
         </td>
      </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `element.innerText` or `element.textContent`, you'll get something like `$ 0.29`.

But you said you wanted a number, so this means that you:

1. Need to parse out the text contents of `.price-amount`,
2. Need to extract the number out of a string.

Here's a working solution:

```
// get first price
const price = document.getElementsByClassName("price-amount")[0].innerText;

// parse price value out of string
const parsedPrice = parseFloat(price.match(/[\d\.]+/))
```

And a codepen with the example: https://codepen.io/cassilup/pen/vadZQG

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the text is to map it out of the elements in which you are interested:

```js
const values = [...document.querySelectorAll('.price-amount')]
  .map(element => element.innerText.replace('$ ', ''))
  
const valueOne = values[0]
const valueTwo = values[1]
const valueThree = values[2]

console.log(valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree)
```

```html
<table class="pricing-rules">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th>Qty </th>
         <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>10-499</td>
         <td>
            <span class="price-amount">
               <span class="currencySymbol">$</span>
               0.29
               </span>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>500-999</td>
         <td>
            <span class="price-amount">
               <span class="currencySymbol">$</span>
               0.28
            </span>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>1000+</td>
         <td>
            <span class="price-amount">
               <span class="currencySymbol">$</span>
               0.26
            </span>
         </td>
      </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Of course, you don't need to put the values from the array into variables, but you did ask for three separate variables.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getPrice(){
        var table = document.getElementById("pricing-rules");
        var array = [];
        for (var r = 1, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
            var spans = jQuery("tr:eq("+r+")").find("td:eq(1)").text().replace(/\s/g,''); //removes every white space
            spans = spans.replace(/\$/g,""); //removes every dollar sign
            array[r] = spans.trim();           
        }        
        array.shift();//removes the first element, because its white space

       //if you want all in different values
       var value1 = array[0];
       var value2 = array[1];
       var value3 = array[2];
       alert("Value 1: "+value1+"\nValue 2: "+value2+"\nValue 3: "+ value3);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="pricing-rules">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th>Qty </th>
         <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>10-499</td>
         <td>
            <span class="price-amount">
               <span class="currencySymbol">$</span> 0.29
               </span>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>500-999</td>
         <td>
            <span class="price-amount">
               <span class="currencySymbol">$</span> 0.28
            </span>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>1000+</td>
         <td>
            <span class="price-amount">
               <span class="currencySymbol">$</span> 
               0.26
            </span>
         </td>
      </tr>
</tbody></table>

<button type="button" onclick="getPrice()">
  Click me!
</button>
```